# Strcpy doesn't work in user defined array

Tags: c, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to assign element hash table[TABLE_SIZE] with input text file. So I used strcpy function. But it didn't copy into the array.

I've tried malloc to make the array in order to write in it. But it didn't work so I made a element* type variable pointing the hash_table array.But still didn't work.

```
    //this is the header file

        typedef struct {
            char key[100];
            char data[100];
        } element;

        element hash_table[TABLE_SIZE];    


        // For caomparison count
        int num_comparison;

        // 파일에서 단어들을 읽어 해시테이블 구성
        int build_dictionary(char *fname);
```

```
        int build_dictionary(char *fname) {
            int  i = 0; // num of data
            char key[100], data[200]; 
            FILE *ifp;

                //pointing to the hash_table array
            element* hash_table_p = hash_table;
            hash_table_p = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element));


                //file opening error
            if ((ifp = fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL) {
                printf("No such file ! \n");
                exit(1);
            }
            while (fscanf(ifp, "%s %s", key, data) == 2) { 
                // (key data) assigning to array

                    //i've tried this because hash_table[i].data didn't work
                strcpy(hash_table_p->data, data);
                strcpy(hash_table_p->key, key);

                    strcpy(hash_table[i].data, hash_table_p->data);
                    strcpy(hash_table[i].key, hash_table_p->key);
                i++;

                 //checking if it is well done
                printf("  %s %s \n", hash_table_p->key, hash_table_p->data);
                printf(" %d %s %s \n",i , hash_table[i].data, hash_table[i].key );
             }
                fclose(ifp);
            return(i);

        }
```

```
//the input text file went as below
one 하나
two 둘
three 셋
four 넷
five 다섯
```

When i executed the build_dictionary function, only one with the hash_table_p strcpy was assigned well and the hash_table had nothing in it.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: `hash_table_p = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element));` is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        element* hash_table_p = hash_table;
        hash_table_p = (element*)malloc(sizeof(element));
```

You are overwritting the first assignment (getting new room for `hash_table_p` when you call `malloc`), as far as I can see you already define the size for the table, so you don't need to reserve more space (delete the line with `malloc`) and just increment the position of the pointer on each iteration (as you are already doing).